# How to fix problem with Roboto font load in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to render my website and I takes a lot of time in Google Chrome, but in Mozilla works perfectly. The console shows the error

```
GET file://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I tried to import directy in the CSS and in the HTML this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic,300italic,300,100italic,100);

body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

But it still doesn't work, it throws the same error.

Here is the full HTML code of my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> </meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"></meta>
        <title>Sign in</title>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
        </style>
        <!-- JQuery Mobile -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"></link>
        <!-- Project CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"></link>
        <!-- NativeDroid2 CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/nativeDroid2/css/nativedroid2.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="img/logo_gemott.png" alt="No es pot carregar la imatge" height="110" width="350">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h2>Registre</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="mail"><b>Correu electrònic</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduir correu electrònic..." name="mail" required>
                    <label for="psw"><b>Contrasenya</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Introduir contrasenya..." name="psw" required>
                    <div class="center-text">
                        <p>Al registrar-te, acceptes els <a href=#>termes de privacitat</a></p>
                        <p>Ja estàs <a href="login.html">registrat?</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a href="javascript:registry()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-raised clr-primary">Registrar-me</a>

                <div class="img-container" id="uab-logo">
                    <img src="img/UAB.jpg" alt="No es pot carrerar la imatge" height="150" witdh="150">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
        <!-- Project Js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery Mobile -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- NativeDroid2 Js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/Waves/dist/waves.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/nativeDroid2/nd2settings.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/nativeDroid2/js/nativedroid2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to import a Google Font, is placing a `link` tag in the `head` section of your HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

At least in the past, using `@import` was problematic when including larger files (font files are quite large) because browsers waited tor the file to download before continuing to render the page.

Your description gives the impression things have improved with Firefox, but not with Chrome.

So I suggest you include the `link` tag in your HTML file's `head`, remove the `style` tag and also remove the line starting with `@import` from your CSS.

As the OP reported an error message, I'm attaching a short example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family:'Roboto'
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now it throws the error ```Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND```

Comment: I don't think the code I suggested is causing this message. See the short example I attached to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;` in `CSS`or `body` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> </meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"></meta>
        <title>Sign in</title>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
          
             body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
       }
          
        </style>
        <!-- JQuery Mobile -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"></link>
        <!-- Project CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"></link>
        <!-- NativeDroid2 CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/nativeDroid2/css/nativedroid2.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="img/logo_gemott.png" alt="No es pot carregar la imatge" height="110" width="350">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h2>Registre</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="mail"><b>Correu electrònic</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduir correu electrònic..." name="mail" required>
                    <label for="psw"><b>Contrasenya</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Introduir contrasenya..." name="psw" required>
                    <div class="center-text">
                        <p>Al registrar-te, acceptes els <a href=#>termes de privacitat</a></p>
                        <p>Ja estàs <a href="login.html">registrat?</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a href="javascript:registry()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-raised clr-primary">Registrar-me</a>

                <div class="img-container" id="uab-logo">
                    <img src="img/UAB.jpg" alt="No es pot carrerar la imatge" height="150" witdh="150">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
        <!-- Project Js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery Mobile -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- NativeDroid2 Js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/Waves/dist/waves.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/nativeDroid2/nd2settings.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/nativeDroid2/js/nativedroid2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

I have tried. It's working!

Comment: The `font-family` already was defined by the OP. If it wasn't, the font wouldn't be displayed in any browser.

Comment: @Pida I know he imported the fonts. but he has not mentioned https in the import statement.

Comment: It's true that OP wrote `http` in his CSS file, but what does this have to do with your answer? You don't mention SSL or `https` and removed that very line in your code sample.

Comment: It's not working, I have the same problem... The fact is that in Mozilla loads perfectly but in Chrome it takes like 20 seconds to load

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

to your `<head>` section.
And this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2") format("woff2")
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: Roboto; }
```

add to your css.
And add the css file with this method:

```
<link rel="preload" href="css/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></noscript>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice. Why two `link` tags in your first code sample, why an additional `src` attribute in the CSS, why the much more complex `link` tag in the third code sample?

Comment: In my first code cell there are two links, because these are two Roboto fonts drawn from [This Link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap). The link contains seven of them, in various alphabets, for example, Cyrillic alphabet. These two are just Latin and Latin-ext. Latin contains all alphanumeric characters, so charging the others separately does not make sense.

Comment: The code constructed in this way is to load the fonts at the same time as the page renders, the last code cell is to load the css code asynchronously, so that there will be no delays when rendering the page.

Answer (score 1):

the URL is not correct
use this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i&display=swap');
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the problem. I'm using a Jquery Mobile theme called NativeDroid2 and it was loading the Roboto font-family incorrectly in the CSS file. I simply commented the url and now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to your site use always HTTPS using htaccess, that's best method to fix this issue

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection may be it is unable to GET it from the provided url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).